# Sumproduct with lookup array

Tags: excel

On one sheet `Total Value`, I have a list of assemblies in `A2:A21`. In the column headers `B1:BA1`, I have the 52 weeks of the year enumerated. I need to populate this matrix with the total value of components used for each assembly in each week.

[image: Total Value Table]

For each assembly `1`,`2`...`20`, there is a sheet with a corresponding name (i.e.,`'1'`,`'2'`...`'20'`) that contains in Column A (`N!A2:...`) the list of components (IDs) and in Column B (`N!B1:...`) the quantity of that component needed for the assembly.

[image: Illustrative Assembly Table]

Additionally, I have another sheet `CV` which contains a table of all components' values by weeks - `CV!A2:A200` containing the component IDs, and `CV!B1:BA1` enumerating the weeks.

[image: Illustrative CV Table]

I am trying to come up with a dynamic formula for each Assembly/Week intersection in `Total Value` that will SUMPRODUCT the quantity of each component needed (from the corresponding assembly sheet) by the value of those components in the given week, given in `CV`.

If there were just one assembly, and `CV` contained only the components needed for that assembly, this would be a simple SUMPRODUCT. Array 1 would contain the component quantities for the assembly, and Array 2 would contain the components' values in that week. In my case, `CV` is a long list in no particular order. I need the second array in the SUMPRODUCT to lookup precisely the values of the components in Array 1 for that week.

I don't even know how to start on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the structure of your tables and it is not so clear.
Could you please attach a picture of your tables structure and manually show one calculation to illustrate for us.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I added illustrative images. Regarding calculations, in `Total Value` for Assembly 1, Week 1, we would sumproduct the quantity of components in the second table by the values of the corresponding components for week 1, given in `CV` table. I have limited the number of rows/column in images to make things visible, but in practice, `CV` will have hundreds of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI try this formula in cell 'Total Value'!B2 :

> =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!A2:A200"),CV!$A$1:$BA$200,B$1+1,0),0),INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!B2:B200"))

It should work if I understand you correctly

Comment: Thanks for this. I have done a few test calculations manually and this is returning different numbers. I think component values in the array returned by the VLOOKUP don't match up with component quantities the second array.

Comment: Hi , thanks for testing it , can you do it once more ? :D forgot to make that Vlookup exact match (I edited it in original answer) I tested it in my version and first few results and it seems fine but please check it again: =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!A2:A200"),CV!$A$1:$BA$200,B$1+1,0),0),INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!B2:B200"))